# Getting "Gas estimation failed" error while deploying EVM contract on Substrate Node?

Tags: evm, gas, solidity

When I try to deploy a solidity smart contract on my substrate node I get the following error:

"Gas estimation failed
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"unknown field `type`, expected one of `from`, `to`, `gasPrice`, `maxFeePerGas`, `maxPriorityFeePerGas`, `gas`, `value`, `data`, `nonce`, `accessList` at line 1 column 8639","id":339420499546212}". How to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: If I send the transaction anyway, I get the following error:

creation of CodeWithJoe errored: Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"[ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{\"value\":{\"code\":-32603,\"data\":{\"code\":-32603,\"message\":\"submit transaction to pool failed: Pool(InvalidTransaction(InvalidTransaction::Custom(3)))\"}}}'","id":4447184481249369}

Comment: have you tried decreasing the gas_fee ?

Comment: @AmitKumarYadav Yes but I get the same error

Comment: is this error comes when you try to transfer tokens?

Comment: No, it's an error when I try to deploy an evm contract on my substrate node.

Comment: can you share the code ?

Answer (score 2):

This error generally occur due to the wrong `gas_estimation` to get rid of this error you can decrease the `gas_fee`of your chain or you can use metamask advance options to set the `gas_limit` manually.you can also decrease the `gas_limit given in remix ide 3000000 to 30000`. you can see [this](https://support.metamask.io/hc/en-us/articles/360022895972-How-to-customize-gas-settings) to customize the `gas_limit` on metamask or you can simply decrease your `gas_fee`.

Comment: Thanks @Amit after decreasing the gas_fee it solves my problem.